# Rstudio and conda: GLIBCXX_3.4.30 not found

Tags: r, rstudio, conda

I get the following error when running `library(stringi)` and many other packages in RStudio. **I do not get this error if I run R in the terminal**.

```
>> library(stringi)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stringi’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/user/miniconda3/envs/r-4.2/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /home/user/miniconda3/envs/r-4.2/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so)
```

More details on the setup.

RStudio `2022.07.2` is installed on the system. R 4.2.2 is installed in a conda environment.R and/or RStudio is always launched from the conda environment. Looking into the `libstdc++.so.6` file, the version in the conda env is newer than that on the system.

`libstdc++.so.6` on system:

```
  strings /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_3.4.29
```

`libstdc++.so.6` in conda

```
  strings miniconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_3.4.29
GLIBCXX_3.4.30
```

- Seems like an RStudio problem since it works fine running R in the terminal and VS Code. I am not using the latest RStudio `2022.12.0` since it doesn't work with conda. The two older versions `2022.07.2` and `2022.02.4` seems to have this same problem. Why doesn't Rstudio just use the `libstdc++.so.6` in the conda environment?
- In the conda env, I cannot downgrade `libstdc++.so.6` to match system because that breaks dependencies
- On the system, I am not sure I can upgrade `libstdc++.so.6` to more than what it is right now probably because it is running older focal Ubuntu 20.04 base. Maybe! Not sure.
- I tried just softlinking `libstdc++.so.6` from conda to system, but that breaks a lot of things

```
  lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Zorin
Description:    Zorin OS 16.2
Release:    16
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: This is [a known issue with newer RStudio builds](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12508) (only broken on Linux). Please add your observations to the issue.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that but I think that is a slightly different issue. That issue is about v2022.12.0 not working when launching from conda. And that is exactly why I am not using v2022.12.0. I am using one version older (v2022.07.2) and it generally works with conda. My issue is to do with `libstdc++.so.6` rather than `libR.so`. But, it could be related. I don't know.

Comment: Is everything from Conda Forge? I.e., DLL errors are often due to improperly mixing channels https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels

Comment: That's an interesting point. I don't think I have carefully looked into this. If I do a `conda iist`, There are 464 packages of whichcat tem 314 are conda-forge and others are just blank.

Comment: Blank means **defaults** channel, so that could be a problem. Try recreating the environment with everything from Conda Forge (though that many packages sounds overkill - maybe consider creating more focused, task-specific environments).